# Java, Overloading method

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, overriding

I have an assignment for class and it's to go over inheritance and overloading and overriding methods.  I think I did everything asked for in the instructions.  However, I am a little confused about overloading and if I did it correctly.  Actually not really sure how it works so I don't know if I did it all.  So you do not have to read through the directions, my main question refers to, the directions that ask "Create two overloaded deposit methods in Account class such that one of them takes an integer value as the input parameter and the second one takes a double value as the input parameter."  and I am not sure I did it correctly.

THANKS FOR ANY HELP!!!

Scott

Instructions available upon request.

Here is what I have....

ACCOUNT CLASS (super class)

```
//Account class
public class Account {
    //create data fields
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    protected int id = 0;
    protected double balance = 0;
    protected double annualInterestRate = 0;
    protected Date dateCreated;

 public Account() {
     dateCreated = new Date();

 }
//constructor for account w/ with id and balance args.
public Account(int newID, double newBalance, double interestRate) {
    dateCreated = new Date();
    id = newID;
    balance = newBalance;
    annualInterestRate = interestRate;
}//end account method

//setter for account ID
public int setID(int newID) {
    return id = newID;
}//end setID

//getter for account ID
public int getID() {
    return id;
}//end getID

//setter for account balance
public void setBalance(double newBalance) {
    balance = newBalance;
}//end setBalance

//getter for account balance
public double getbalance() {
    return balance;
}//end method getBalance

//setter for accounts annual interest rate
public void setAnnualInterestrate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
}//end setAnnualInterestRate

//getter for accounts annual interest rate
public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
}//end getAnnualInterestRate

//getter for date account was created   
public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}//end getDateCreated

//calls the annual interest rate and divides by 12 to get the monthly rate 
public double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
    return (annualInterestRate) / 12;
}//end getMonthlyInterestRate

//method to make a withdrawal from account      
public double withdraw(double withdrawAmount) {
    balance -= withdrawAmount;
    return withdrawAmount;
}   

//two overload method to make a deposit from account
public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
    balance += depositAmount;
}

public void deposit(int depositAmount) {
    balance += depositAmount;
}
}
```

SAVINGS ACCOUNT CLASS

```
public class SavingAccount extends Account {

public SavingAccount(int newID, double newBalance, double interestRate) {
    super(newID, newBalance, interestRate);
}

public double withdraw(double withdrawAmount){

    if(balance >= withdrawAmount){
      return super.withdraw(withdrawAmount);
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("You cannot be overdraw your Savings Account!  \nThe max you will be allowed to withdraw is: " + balance + "\n");
      setBalance(0);
      return balance;
    }
} 

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Account ID: " + id + "\nBalance: " + balance + "\nAnnual Interest rate: "
            + annualInterestRate + "\nDate of the Account Creation:" + dateCreated;
}

}
```

CHECKING ACCOUNT CLASS

```
public class CheckingAccount extends Account{
double overDraft = 5000;

public CheckingAccount(int newID, double newBalance, double interestRate) {
super(newID, newBalance, interestRate);    
}

public double getOverdraft() {
    return overDraft;
  }

public void setOverdraft(double overdraft) {
     overDraft = 5000;
}
public double withdraw(double withdrawAmount){
    double balance = getbalance();


  if(balance - withdrawAmount >= -overDraft){
      return super.withdraw(withdrawAmount);
}
else{
  System.out.println("reach overdraf limit!");
  setBalance(-overDraft);
  return overDraft + getbalance();
}
}  

@Override
public String toString() {
  return "Account ID: " + id + "\nBalance: " + balance + "\nAnnual Interest rate: "
         + annualInterestRate + "\nDate of the Account Creation:" + dateCreated;
}
}
```

TESTACCOUNT CLASS

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestAccount {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int accID = 0;
    double balance = 0;
    double intRate = 0;
    double withDraw = 0;
    double Deposit = 0;

    //savings account
    System.out.println("Please enter the ID of the Savings Account: ");
    accID = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the initial Balance of the Savings Account: ");
    balance = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the Interest Rate of the Savings Account: ");
    intRate = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();

    SavingAccount s = new SavingAccount(accID, balance, intRate);
    System.out.println("Please enter an amount you would like to Withdraw from the Savings Account: ");
    withDraw = scan.nextDouble();
    s.withdraw(withDraw);
    System.out.println("Please enter an amount you would like to Deposit into the Savings Account: ");
    Deposit = scan.nextDouble();
    s.deposit(Deposit);
    System.out.println("\nSavings Account Status:\n" + s);



    //Checking account
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the ID of the Checking Account: ");
    accID = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the initial Balance of the Checking Account: ");
    balance = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the Interest Rate of the Checking Account: ");
    intRate = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();

    CheckingAccount c = new CheckingAccount(accID, balance, intRate);
    System.out.println("Please enter an amount you would like to Withdraw from the Checking Account: ");
    withDraw = scan.nextDouble();
    c.withdraw(withDraw);
    System.out.println("Please enter an amount you would like to Deposit into the Checking Account: ");
    Deposit = scan.nextDouble();
    c.deposit(Deposit);
    System.out.println("\nChecking Account Status:\n" + c);

}
}
```

Also, is there anything else you would change to make the program better?

Comment: Is it a question or an essay?

Comment: So, what's your specific problem?  What behavior do you get and what do you expect instead?

Comment: Sorry it's so long.  I am super new to programming in general and my question is, the directions ask to make two overloading deposit methods in Account class and I am not sure I did it correctly.  Not really sure what it means exactly.  Every time I reread the book/slides I get confused.

Comment: I rewrote the beginning paragraph to make my question easier to read and so you do not have to read through all the directions if you don't want to.

Comment: Confusion tends to happen when you are behind schedule and try to rush things.

Comment: @user3862586 nobody would like to read such a long question. Remove non-trivial details such as Submission deadline. Do some work

Comment: What does that mean?  I got this assignment yesterday at 4pm, did the first part and submitted it before end of class.  Woke up at 5am went to school, then work, then started finishing up the assignment 2 hours ago.  I have until midnight.  I'm not behind schedule trying to play catch up.  You shouldn't make comments you know nothing about.  If you do not care to assist, move on.  Your comments are completely unnecessary though!

Comment: Guys, there is one paragraph that needs to be read.  I put the directions in there in case anyone wanted to clarify what the assignment is or what I was talking about.  You should not have to read more than the first paragraph though.

Comment: Ankush- what do you mean do some work?

Comment: Was that so hard everyone else??? I don't understand why everyone was getting so upset when you could've answered my question in less time it took to complain!  I'm new here and to programming, cut some people a little slack.  FYI, it was how you responded not what was said.  It could've been done politely!

Comment: Well, you posted a lot of irrelevant details, which makes it look like you haven't really thought through which parts are relevant.  I didn't even read most of your question before writing my answer:  I read the paragraph at the top that says what you're looking for, then skimmed down through your `Account` class looking for some overloaded methods.  The rest is extraneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//two overload method to make a deposit from account
public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
    balance += depositAmount;
}

public void deposit(int depositAmount) {
    balance += depositAmount;
}
```

Yes, these are overloaded methods.  You did it correctly.

Comment: @Whyzard  Any chance you could give a quick explanation of why they are overload methods?

Comment: Because they have the same name (`deposit`) but different argument types (`double` and `int`).  That's what overloading means.

Comment: Oh ok! Override, overrides the method of the super class and overload overloads the methods data type?  Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Overriding means the same name *and* argument types as a method from a superclass, so that when something calls that method on your object, it gets your new version instead of the original.  They have to have the same name and argument types, or the one wouldn't be an override of the other.  Overloaded methods, in contrast, are independent of each other; you could rename one and it wouldn't affect the other.

Comment: BTW, this program isn't a good example of why to use overloading, because there's no real need for the `deposit(int)` method (aside from your assignment requiring it).  Even if that method didn't exist, you could still call `deposit` with an `int` value, because the `int` gets converted automatically to `double` and passed to the `deposit(double)` method.